# Do I need to use a 'nonce' token in ASP.NET WebForms to guard against CSRF?

Tags: security, webforms, csrf

In an ASP.NET WebForms application which:

1. Sets the `ViewStateUserKey` to the session ID via

   ```
   protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
   {
       base.OnInit(e);
       if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
           ViewStateUserKey = Session.SessionID;
   }
   ```

   on the derived base page
2. Uses only POSTbacks to perform any sensitive actions
3. `EnableViewStateMac` is always enabled

Do I still need to implement a hidden form field value with a random token that is checked for on subsequent requests to mitigate against CSRF attacks??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a complete method of protection against CSRF.  Any non-postback request,  such as GET is still vulnerable.  Also I haven't used this method and to be honest ViewState manipulation can be a much more serious vulnerability.   The idea of giving the viewstate to the client isn't a defense in-depth approach.    A Cryptographic Nonce is a very good solution to the problem and thats why its most commonly used. But its not the only solution, you should read the [CSRF Prevention Cheat Sheet](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).  For the record a Nonce just means a value that is only used once,  a primary key is a nonce,  but thats doesn't stop CSRF.  You need a cryptographic nonce,  which is a value that is only used once,  **AND** its very difficult to guess.

Comment: But isn't the view state encrypted and checked for tampering on every postback? If there are no GET requests that could cause any update or change in the application, what could be exploited using a CSRF GET to a URL?

Comment: @Omar yeah but crypto systems fail.  "Defense in depth", you should plan on failure.  This state should be manage server side,  a user keeping track of viewstate is a waste of bandwidth, cpu time and is fundamentally insecure.

Comment: @Omar Before the asp.net oracle padding attack the excuse was "We can store state in the cookie,  its ENCRYPTED!".  Yeah,  except it can be broken and on some systems remote code execution became possible.  This is a gross misuse of encryption, a session id should always be using a cryptographic nonce,

Comment: So the only drawback of using the session ID is that it has a higher probability of being cracked than a cryptographically generated token? I'm still unclear whether or not an application - as described by my question - would be vulnerable to a CSRF attack assuming none of my encrypted data is cracked.

Comment: @Omar No,  a session id is far more difficult to guess.  Also a CSRF attack isn't going to involve cracking of a token like this,  there are far more serious risks with such a bad design.